# Why is my old Nvidia card failing to start?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, troubleshooting

I'd like to add a third monitor to my computer.

Unfortunately, my primary Nvidia graphics card only supports two DVI monitors, so I decided to take an old Nvidia graphics card from another computer and placed it in my motherboard's conventional PCI slot.

Once I restarted my computer, Windows was not able to find a driver from Windows Update, so it installed a "Standard VGA Graphics Adapter" driver with a warning icon on it. The error is a code 10 error (`This device cannot start`). I attempted to install an old driver that is compatible with the secondary card, but this simply ended up with a bugcheck (`IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`) since the old drivers seemed to replace the newer ones. I had to reinstall the new drivers in Safe Mode in order to get the system operational.

However, this doesn't solve the problem. I suspected at first that the cause was an IRQ/resource conflict, but Device Manager does not quite explain the IRQs of nonworking devices. Using HWiNFO, the card name and rudimentary data is shown for the older card, but there is no indication that it is operational.

Is my card supposed to run correctly under generic drivers? Is this a WDDM problem? Or is this, as I had suspected, an IRQ conflict that cannot be resolved through normal means?

**Specs**:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- 8 GB RAM
- GeForce GTS 240 (primary)
- PNY Technologies GeForce FX 5200 (problem card)

**Other notes:**

- The old PC used 32-bit Windows Vista; the card handled it perfectly.
- My motherboard only has one PCIe port, so I cannot add a more modern secondary video card.
- I am only interested in a three-monitor setup. I am not interested in any gaming with the secondary card.

Comment: If I'm not entirely mistaken, the GTS240 requires a driver that considers the FX5200 to be "legacy" and does not support it. And unfortunately it is not possible to install multiple versions of the NVidia drivers in parallel.

Comment: @datenwolf That's something I've discovered, so I've given up on installing manufacturer-specific drivers for the FX5200. Now what I want to do is try removing the GTS 240 and booting Windows up and see how Windows handles it. In programs like Speccy, the 240 seems to be conflicting with the FX5200 in specifications.

Comment: You won't be able to use the old card with the new card.  You have a driver conflict and the version of Windows your using is not going to allow two vastly different display drivers to be used.  I see no evidence the card is about to fail.

Comment: @Ramhound If this were true, one would not be able to use an AMD card alongside an Nvidia one. Guess what? When I removed the GTS240, the card with generic driver worked. Both for some reason have an IRQ of 16. So my hypothesis seems to be correct so far. Only thing I've found is that the generic driver doesn't support WDDM.

Comment: I was specific with my comment or I should have been the problem doesn't happen with AMD and Nvidia cards because the display driver isn't literally the same driber, the 2 cards, are simply two spread across generations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Verdict

The card won't work alongside my primary one. Okay sure just because it's old right? *No.*

The last driver that supports the GeForce FX 5200 is, in fact, WDDM 1.0-compatible. This is why people report to have working Aero, but only when the drivers are installed. As an aside, the 5200 was one of the first to support DirectX 9, at least at a rudimentary level. Because this final driver cannot be installed with the primary card (as the primary card's oldest compatible driver is many versions further), the primary card tries to load these old drivers and evokes a bugcheck.

I tried to splice the new and old drivers together, but it did something awkward that led to another type of BSoD that appeared for such a brief moment that I could not even read it.

The "Standard VGA Graphics Adapter" (`vgapnp.sys`) that Windows resorts to when it can't find a driver is apparently not compatible with WDDM. A non-WDDM driver cannot be loaded with a WDDM driver, so the driver fails to start, showing a Code 10 failure. *This* is the reason I will never be able to use the cards together. This is also the reason why the 5200 can start by itself, but not when the 240 is around.

The IRQ was a red herring: although ACPI gives Windows full control in assigning IRQs to devices, there is a feature in the PCI bus called *IRQ steering*, which means that multiple devices can occupy the same IRQ with no conflict. (If you run two PCIe x16 cards together, the two cards only use x8 bus width.)

While the card is capable (in performance) of working with my computer, there is no driver that is new enough to support it.

Sadly, I will have to scrap the whole three-monitor proposition. I have many spare monitors, but the PSU doesn't appear to be able to handle two middle-end cards simultaneously. Moreover, my motherboard only has one PCIe x16 port. There is physically no way to fit a cheap, new card into another slot.

Comment: Maybe look into USB 2.0/3.0 display adapters.

Comment: @ultrasawblade I've considered them, but they are quite pricey and don't look very reliable.